# BigQuery Data Transfer for Google Play - Missing New Users/Returning Users Metric

Tags: google-bigquery, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api, google-cloud-data-transfer

I've recently set up a BigQuery data transfer to import data from Google Play, and overall, the process has been smooth. However, I've encountered an issue regarding the availability of the "New Users/Returning Users" metric for app downloads.

On the Google Play dashboard, this metric is readily available. However, I haven't been able to find a way to export this specific metric to BigQuery through the data transfer process.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue, and if so, were you able to find a workaround or solution to include the "New Users/Returning Users" metric in your BigQuery data transfer setup? Are there any specific steps or configurations that I might be missing?